# Mesh got damaged while modeling

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

My Mesh is damaged as shown in pic, I was modelling a Dinosaur and could not see other side, but suddenly when i checked there is some damaged mesh shown in pic. I was using Sculpting before that. Can anyone tell what is the problem in it ?? I have uploaded the blend file here - 
https://filebin.net/wnzix0e6s7s23bk8/BabyBoss.blend?t=aegqgh60

I am learning blender and not sure where i did mistake, can you help me how to rectify?

Comment: You have a bad topology on this part of your mesh, like edge crossing faces, even if you fix the topology it won't fix your problem, but it may have messed up with your sculpting (? just an hypothesis). So maybe fix the topology, then delete your Multires and recreate one?

Answer (score 1):

With such a complex model, you should find the way to make a loop cut in the middle of it (down the spine of the animal). Eliminate the damaged side and use a mirror modifier. That should fix it and help you go faster overall.